# I would like to make a Pattern that give standard output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose the height is 4 and the width is 8

the result will:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

i am a beginner i was trying it like

```
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        print(j, sep='  ', end=' ', flush=True)
    print()
```

but it need to print 1 to 9 and new line will be printed after the width , what should be the approach?

Comment: You would need a separate counter that would increment independently and print that, and not print `i` and `j` as that's tracking the position of the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea. I modified your code to use a counter variable, and then write it mod 10.

```py
height = 4
width = 8

counter = 0
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        print(counter%10, sep='  ', end=' ', flush=True)
        counter+=1
    print()
```